# Как сделать, чтобы страница загрузилась после того как запустится скрипт js, ибо происходит мерцание?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Изменяю css стили с помощью js, происходит мерцание при перезагрузке страницы или перелистываниии с стр на стр, можно ли страницу грузить после срабатывания скрипта, чтобы не видеть мерцание?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делают наоборот. Запуск скриптов когда уже весь DOM собран, собстенно, что б переменным скрипта было с чем работать. Почитать про это можно тут https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Answer (score 0):

Если кому будет полезно, для себя нашёл такой вариант, body задать `display:none;`.
А уже после выполнения скрипта body задать `display:block;`.
В итоге мерцания не будет видно.